# Accessing async Task<X>.Result in synchronous thread safe?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety, .net-4.5

If I have a .NET 4.5 asynchronous task method, for example:

```
 public async Task<String> GetData()

 (...)

 return await MyObject.GetSomethingAsynchronous();
```

And then somewhere else in a **synchronous** thread (e.g. a non-async method), I call this:

```
 String myString = MyObject.GetData().Result;
```

Is this safe to do or bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Task.Result` is generally not recommended. A better solution is to `await` the `Task` and change the containing method to be `async`, allowing the asynchronous code to grow up through the code base.

There are two problems with `Task.Result` as compared to `await` (other than the fact that it blocks rather than asynchronously waiting):

1. You can easily get into a deadlock situation where the `Task` needs a particular thread (e.g., a UI thread) to complete but that thread is blocked on that `Task`. I explain this in more detail [on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).
2. Any errors thrown from the `async` method will be wrapped in an `AggregateException`, which makes exception handling much more complex. `await` will unwrap the underlying error, allowing you to use a much more natural `catch(MyExceptionType)`.

Comment: There some scenarios where blocking is the preferred behavior as when you are already functioning on a worker thread or you where the calling framework presupposes resources are only needed for the length of call (i.e. Akka.NET).

Comment: @Jordan: Blocking isn't preferred on worker threads - async code works fine and is more natural (as well as more efficient). If a framework call requires blocking (which is still a somewhat common situation today), then I tend to view this as a limitation of the framework.

Comment: Akka.NET is brand new. It does have support for TPL but it makes for very messy code; you cannot use async/await. The point of an actor is that you do not want it to return the call until it is completely done. I don't mean to digress. My point is only that there are always exceptions to rules. You are generally correct.

Comment: @Jordan: It can be new and still have a limitation. It's not too hard to support asynchronous actors, if they wanted to. Just return `Task`/`Task<T>` (for a convention/interface-style framework), or use a [deferral system](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html) (for a callback/event-style framework).

Comment: Nevermind, you can use Task within the Akka.NET ReceiveActor type.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes.

From your question I gather that you think of `Task` as `something executed in separate thread` which is not necessarily correct. Asyc mechanism is more generic then that and it allows to do stuff in the meantime while you wait - for thread to end as one, for web request to return value, for file system to read file, and for whatever else you want to. This is nothing more then fancy syntactic sugar that allows you not to be bothered with patterns like this:

```
void DoSomethingTimeConsumingThatWillNotBlockThisThread(Action onFinishContinue);
```

consider this simple program:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        GetPoint();
    }

    public async void GetPoint()
    {
        var point = await RetrivePointAsync();
        MessageBox.Show(point.ToString());
    }

    public Task<Point> RetrivePointAsync()
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<Point>(
             (callback, state) => new Handler(this, callback),
             x => ((Handler)x).Point, null);
    }
}
```

Just to prove my point I attached to event and I'm **awaiting** for users click so no threads involved.

```
class Handler : IAsyncResult
{
    AsyncCallback _calback;
    public Point Point { get; set; }
    public object AsyncState { get { return null; } }
    public bool CompletedSynchronously { get { return false; } }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle { get { return null; } }

    public Handler(Control control, AsyncCallback calback)
    {
        _calback = calback;
        control.MouseDown += control_MouseDown;
    }

    void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point = e.Location;
        IsCompleted = true;
        _calback(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: But in order for you to continue on your thread ("allows you to do stuff in the meantime while you wait") doesn't that necessarily mean whatever is await-ed must be in a separate thread?

Comment: not necessary. You need to grasp [difference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/csharplanguage/thread/3de8670c-49ca-400f-a1dc-ce3a3619357d) between [asynchronous programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) and multithreading.